# Change toc depth of rmdformats::material

Tags: css, r-markdown

Is there a way to change the toc depth of a Rmarkdown document with rmdformats::material from the default to 2 (in case of material) or even 3? Probably you have to change the css style but I don't have a clue how to do that.
Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a code example of what you are trying to do, I went ahead and will try to answer anyways

```
---
output: rmdformats::material
---

# header1

# header2

# header3
```

Looks like the TOC depth that I think you are talking about is referring to the leavel 1 headers, so however many headers you make, that's how long the TOC dept will be. Unless I misunderstood your question

[image]

Comment: More specific: rmdformats material shows only the 1 level headers in toc. with toc_depth you are normally able to change how many toc levels will be displayed but this doesn't work with rmdformat templates. I thought there would be a way to change the css template and display more than one toc level